# I want to display my EXCEL data with "%" sign. How can i do so by using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

i am creating an Excel data sheet where i need to show my data both in number and with a percentage sign. but when i use percentage from Excel data type it adds some extra zero (9600%). but i don't want it like this. my requirement for data is only with the percentage sign (96%). Can i do this by using Excel of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `0.42` as value for your cell will lead to `42%` - setting `42` into that cell, you will get `4200%`.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook  # openpyxel 2.5.9

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
_cell = ws.cell(1,1)
_cell.number_format = '%'
_cell.value = 42                   # 4200 %

_cell = ws.cell(2,1)
_cell.number_format = '%'
_cell.value = 0.42                 # 42 %

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

[image: formatting]

---

In case you use earlier versions of openpyxel or other packages to create your excel the syntax might differ, the solution should be the same. Set a *below-one* float as cell value to get percentages less then 100%.